# Get total records per date

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a simple `List` of Customer records:

```
Customer
  Name
  Age
  DateTimeOfThing
```

Using Linq, I need to know how many customers there were for each day, when `DateTimeOfThing` is a `DateTime`.

Something like this:

```
1-April-2013     23
2-April-2013     3
3-April-2013     123
```

My source is like this:

```
var myList = new List<Customer>() ....
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var res = myList
    .GroupBy(z => z.DateTimeOfThing.Date)
    .Select(z => new
    {
        Count = z.Count(),
        Date = z.Key
    });
```

Comment: @David Yes, it is a concern.  If there are two dates on the same day but at different times he wants them to be in the same group, not in two different groups.  If you didn't include the `.Date` they'd be in different groups.

Comment: @Servy, haha, you are correct! as we need to sort it by that... thanks

Comment: @David No, we're not sorting anything.  We're *grouping*.